# How to set up a dropdown menu to overlay container

Tags: html, css

I've created a sub menu using html/css and I'm now trying to apply a dropdown on these links but I'm struggling to bring the dropdown up. As you can see it's now stuck within the container. Here is the link:
https://vitrinemedia.ca/retail-test  (I'm using wordpress)

```css
.menu-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.dropbtn {
  color: #1a1a1a;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

/* The container  - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 5;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-row">
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropbtn"><strong>STOREFRONT</strong></div>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropbtn"><strong>STORE DISPLAY</strong></div>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I took out some if the html cause the code was too long so I've just copy the first and last div.

Thank you so much for your help,

Comment: please add html (and your link is broken)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to publish the page, here it is now. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.grve-background-wrapper` and `#grve-theme-wrapper .grve-section[data-section-type="fullwidth-background"]` are both set to *overflow: hidden*

If you set them both to *overflow: visible* then the dropdown will come out of the box.

Comment: Great! Can you mark my answer as correct and upvote, thanks!